# What do repeated block:block_rq_complete events mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

I'm trying to use Linux Perf Events to understand block device IO.  I'm monitoring insert, issue and complete.  I sometimes get traces like:

```
$ perf script | grep 720056912
jbd2/sda5-8   203 368748.496400: block:block_rq_insert: 8,0 FWFS 0 () 720056912 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
swapper     0 368748.518255: block:block_rq_issue: 8,0 WS 0 () 720056912 + 8 [swapper/0]
swapper     0 368748.518545: block:block_rq_complete: 8,0 WS () 720056912 + 8 [0]
swapper     0 368748.529398: block:block_rq_complete: 8,0 WS () 720056912 + 0 [0]
```

Judging by adjacent sched:sched_wakeup events, the second complete is the real one.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  Is there any way to tell the first complete isn't enough besides seeing the second one?  I'm fine with turning on more events.